# Content Type troubles with HTTParty against Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, httparty

```
require 'HTTParty'
require 'json'

@payload ={
    "email" => "phil@gmail.com",
    "token" => "mytokenstuff",
    "content" => "here is some content",
    "notification_type" => "1",
    "name" => "here is a name",
    "auto_action" => "true"
 }

response = HTTParty.post('http://localhost:3000/api/create.json', :body =>JSON.dump(@payload), :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } )
```

In my rails controller, the header is coming in ContentType text/html.  So obviously my headers param isn't working....

ideas?

Answer (score 16):

Try it this way:

```
HTTParty.post(
  'http://localhost:3000/api/create.json', 
  :body => JSON.dump(@payload), 
  :headers => {
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 
  }
)
```

Try to add `Accept` too:

```
:headers => {
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 
  'Accept' => 'application/json'
}
```

Also, check that it is not grabbing the options from a cookie - clean the cookies.

Comment: I tried this too.  Same result, the request is received as text/html, not application/json.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `'Content-Type'` instead of `'ContentType'`?

Answer (score 0):

`HTTParty.post(<some link>, :body => "This is the body", :headers => {"Content-Type" => "text/html"})`

Same as:

```
options = {:body => "Same body", :headers => {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}}`
HTTParty.post(<same link>, options)`
```